# Not using magento default logo option

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it ok if I not use the default magento logo option and display a logo via a static block? I mean I want to leave both the logo fields empty and alt text as well in Design->Header fields.

Answer (score 0):

There are no any problem if you not use default functionality.you need to modify current theme header.phtml file code for logo

```
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
    <?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif?>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Do I just paste this code in header.phtml and that is all. How would search engines know the new logo?

Comment: That is location of code where from logo rendering if you need to use your code comment above code and place your code there.

Comment: Can you please tell me the code that I need to use?

Comment: above code you need to use replace your logo image with <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" />

Comment: Can you please tell me why I need to do this? As I am displaying logo through a static block.

Comment: Then place your static block in header file <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>